# Counting Related Records : Query Taking Over 2 Minutes To Run

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image: ER Sample]

Considering the diagram above I am trying to select bulletins along with related info.

1. A bulletin can have only one associated user (the creator)
2. A bulletin can have only one state (the creator's home state)
3. A bulletin can have only one bulletin type (E.G. Announcement, for sale, etc)
4. A bulletin can have 0 or 1 event tied to it
5. A bulletin can have many likes
6. A bulletin can have many comments

As far as the states go a region can have many states

Using the query below causes it to run for 2 minutes before I hit the cancel button. I have not tried to run it for more than that.

```
SELECT TOP 10 Bulletins.Id, LEFT(Bulletins.Body, 350) AS BodySnippet, Bulletins.CreationDateTime
, Bulletins.UserId AS PosterId, Bulletins.StateId, Bulletins.EventId,
Bulletins.BulletinTypeId, Bulletins.[Views], Users.UserName,
Users.Zipcode as ZipCode, Users.StateId as StateId, Users.City,
States.Name, States.UnitedStatesRegionId, RegionsOfTheUnitedStates.Name,
COUNT(BulletinLikes.Id) AS Likes, COUNT(BulletinComments.Id) AS Comments
FROM Bulletins
INNER JOIN Users ON Bulletins.UserId = Users.Id
INNER JOIN States ON Bulletins.StateId = States.Id
INNER JOIN RegionsOfTheUnitedStates ON States.UnitedStatesRegionId = RegionsOfTheUnitedStates.Id
INNER JOIN BulletinTypes ON Bulletins.BulletinTypeId = BulletinTypes.Id
LEFT JOIN [Events] ON Bulletins.EventId = [Events].Id
LEFT JOIN BulletinLikes ON Bulletins.Id = BulletinLikes.BulletinId
LEFT JOIN BulletinComments ON Bulletins.Id = BulletinComments.BulletinId
GROUP BY Bulletins.Id, Bulletins.Body, Bulletins.CreationDateTime
, Bulletins.UserId, Bulletins.StateId, Bulletins.EventId,
Bulletins.BulletinTypeId, Bulletins.[Views], Users.UserName,
Users.Zipcode, Users.StateId, Users.City,
States.Name, States.UnitedStatesRegionId, RegionsOfTheUnitedStates.Name
```

Deleting the line that does the counting of Likes and Comments makes the query return back instantaneously. In my tables I have lots of dummy data. Some of these bulletins have hundreds or a couple thousand likes or comments. That still does not seem like enough to make the query run for 2 minutes plus+ I am no expert when it comes to TSQL so I know it is boiling down to how I'm counting or how I am grouping.

**What would be the proper way to return the counted related records in my specific scenario?**

**EDIT 1*
My ER is c*ompletely off on one part. I closed out of the website I was using to create it and lost it. Here are some corrections

- Bulletins is tied to BulletinTypes with a BulletinTypeFK inside of the Bulletins table (reason being is we use Bulletintypes for a drop down)

**EDIT 2**

I just found out you can do some profiling on SQL Azure and came up with these two sreenshots of information; however, I'm not 100% sure what to gain from these.
[image]
[image]

It looks as if the first sort operation is taking up 54.2% of resources. The first index seek looks pretty high too @ 32.2%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the counts then those left joins don't even need to be performed and the query optimizer probably figures it out.

And you don't even user Events with the count - drop it

Make sure you have indexes on all those join conditions (BullitinID) and they are not fragmented.

When these two queries run fast your query will run fast

```
select count(distinct(BulletinId)) from BulletinLikes  
select count(distinct(BulletinId)) from BulletinComments
```

(and you may need an index on regionId)

```
SELECT TOP 10 Bulletins.Id, LEFT(Bulletins.Body, 350) AS BodySnippet
            , Bulletins.CreationDateTime
            , Bulletins.UserId AS PosterId, Bulletins.StateId, Bulletins.EventId
            , Bulletins.BulletinTypeId, Bulletins.[Views]
            , Users.UserName, Users.Zipcode as ZipCode, Users.StateId as StateId, Users.City
            , States.Name, States.UnitedStatesRegionId
            , RegionsOfTheUnitedStates.Name
            , COUNT(BulletinLikes.Id) AS Likes
            , COUNT(BulletinComments.Id) AS Comments
FROM Bulletins
INNER JOIN Users 
   ON Bulletins.UserId = Users.Id
INNER JOIN States 
   ON Bulletins.StateId = States.Id
INNER JOIN RegionsOfTheUnitedStates 
   ON States.UnitedStatesRegionId = RegionsOfTheUnitedStates.Id
INNER JOIN BulletinTypes 
   ON Bulletins.BulletinTypeId = BulletinTypes.Id
LEFT JOIN [Events] 
  ON Bulletins.EventId = [Events].Id
LEFT JOIN BulletinLikes 
  ON Bulletins.Id = BulletinLikes.BulletinId
LEFT JOIN BulletinComments 
  ON Bulletins.Id = BulletinComments.BulletinId
GROUP BY Bulletins.Id, Bulletins.Body, Bulletins.CreationDateTime 
       , Bulletins.UserId, Bulletins.StateId, Bulletins.EventId
       , Bulletins.BulletinTypeId, Bulletins.[Views]
       , Users.UserName, Users.Zipcode, Users.StateId, Users.City
       , States.Name, States.UnitedStatesRegionId
       , RegionsOfTheUnitedStates.Name
```

Comment: Okay perhaps the reason could be that all my PKs are clustered?

Comment: Keep your PK.  Add a noncluseterd index to BullitinID on those tables.

Comment: Okay I am looking into it

Comment: I created the indexes. After doing this is there anything else I need to do? It does not seem like it's doing anything

Comment: Oh my goodness it should have fixed it.  Post a the index on select =m BulletinLikes.  And the query plan for select count(distinct(BulletinId)) from BulletinLikes

Comment: You want to know something funny? The whole reason I was doing this was because my entity framework query was taking way too long to run. It would take 5 seconds and time out some times on the first execution. Now that you had me add these indexes its super fast lol. SQL crisis averted.

Comment: then like give it the check

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I'd try to check performance of much simpler query that touches tables that have the most effect (you mentioned BulletinLikes and BulletinComments are the biggest offenders of performance) :

```
SELECT TOP 10 b.id, COUNT(bl.Id) AS likes, COUNT(bc.Id) AS Comments 
FROM Bulletins b 
LEFT JOIN BulletinLikes bl ON b.Id = bl.BulletinId
LEFT JOIN BulletinComments ON b.Id = bc.BulletinId
GROUP BY b.id
```

If that gives decent performance, I'd make it subquery or CTE, whatever syntax you prefer, and join the rest to the result of subquery.

The general idea is to get rid of huge `GROUP BY` ...

Side note : `TOP` without `ORDER BY` is not guaranteed to give consistent results.

Comment: But all the values derive from b.id

Comment: They logically do, but optimizer may choose not optimal execution plan (`group by` in many cases implicitly sorts temporary resultset)

Comment: This actually ran very fast. The time registered was 00:00:00

Comment: I also executed it without the `TOP 10` and it took 11 seconds to run on 1020 bulletins with up tp 30,000 related records per bulletin.

Comment: Next step would be adding joins from the original query , something like `WITH cte1 AS [query from the answer] SELECT a.*, ... FROM cte1 a INNER JOIN Bulletins b ON (b.id = a id) INNER JOIN Users ....` . Then check whether it returns desired results - you may need to tweak it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the form of your query (although you may want to consider if you need to select so many columns, but that is beside the point).

You may want to focus on the **indexes** that exist on all of the columns in your **join conditions**.  Most of the time, we join on columns that are in a foreign key relationship to a primary key, and thus there is likely a (default) clustered index on that column, but you'll want to check to be sure: each of these columns should be the first column in some index on each of the tables in question (at least for the tables with more than a trivial number of rows).

Comment: Hello Patrick, I just double checked my index and they definitely are there and are clustered.

Comment: Hmm, well, it is a little odd to count items from two separate joins in one query (but it could be correct).  Could it work for you to count likes in one query and comments in another?  Just a thought.

Comment: One thing you could try to paste in here to help us is the execution plan.  Try a `SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON` and then run your query.

Comment: I just tried it but I am not sure I did it right. It returned an STMText with a bunch of steps. Is that correct?

Comment: See my answer.  Not a PK clustered index.  You need an nonclustered index on on BulletinId.

Comment: Yes, the steps with the costs of each step would be helpful to see exactly where the slowdown is.  Blam may be right.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski I found some tools on Azure that let you profile your query if you could take a look at the screen shots I just put in the OP

Comment: Sounds like you got it figured out with Blam.  The sort was needed so that the DBMS could count the elements in each row of the grouping values.  By counting an indexed column, you were able to speed this up.

Answer (score 0):

I would try pulling the COUNT fields out into sub-queries, and avoid the whole GROUP BY statement:

```
SELECT TOP 10 Bulletins.Id, LEFT(Bulletins.Body, 350) AS BodySnippet, Bulletins.CreationDateTime, Bulletins.UserId AS PosterId, Bulletins.StateId, Bulletins.EventId, Bulletins.BulletinTypeId, Bulletins.[Views], Users.UserName, Users.Zipcode as ZipCode, Users.StateId as StateId, Users.City, States.Name, States.UnitedStatesRegionId, RegionsOfTheUnitedStates.Name,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BulletinLikes bl WHERE bl.BulletinId = b.Id) AS Likes,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BulletinComments bc WHERE bc.BulletinId = b.Id) AS Comments
FROM Bulletins
INNER JOIN Users ON Bulletins.UserId = Users.Id
INNER JOIN States ON Bulletins.StateId = States.Id
INNER JOIN RegionsOfTheUnitedStates ON States.UnitedStatesRegionId = RegionsOfTheUnitedStates.Id
INNER JOIN BulletinTypes ON Bulletins.BulletinTypeId = BulletinTypes.Id
LEFT JOIN [Events] ON Bulletins.EventId = [Events].Id
```